# Help to prove the condition that a right half-open interval is not empty

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

The right half-open interval is defined as:

$[a,b) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}|a \le x \lt b\}$

I need to prove:

$[a,b) \ne \emptyset \iff a<b$

My attempt:

For $\Rightarrow$:

$$\begin{align}
[a,b)\ne \emptyset & \Rightarrow & a\le x \lt b \\
&\Rightarrow & a\le x \text{ and } x \lt b \\
& \Rightarrow & a \lt b
\end{align}$$

For $\Leftarrow$:

$\begin{align}
a<b & \Rightarrow & 2a < a+b \text{ and } a+b < 2b\\
& \Rightarrow & 2a<a+b<2b \\
& \Rightarrow & a< \frac{a+b}{2} < b \\
& \Rightarrow & (a,b)
\end{align}$

I don't know how to start with $a<b$ and imply $a\le x <b$. I face similar problem too with a left half-open interval, $(a,b]$

Comment: If $a<b$ then $x_1=a \in [a,\ b)$ and $x_2=\frac{a+b}{2} \in [a,\ b).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your definition of a right-open interval
$$ [a\,,\,b] = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \,|\, a \leq x < b \} $$
We want to prove
$$ [a , b] \neq \emptyset \Leftrightarrow a < b $$

$\textbf{Case } (\Rightarrow) $ :

As $[a\,,\,b) \neq \emptyset$, there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \in [a\,,\,b)$. This $x$ satisfies the condition
$$ a \leq x < b $$
Substracting by $a$ on both sides, we obtain
$$ 0 \leq x - a < b -a \;\; \Rightarrow 0 < b - a$$
so that we have $a < b$. ($\Rightarrow$) is proved.

$\textbf{Case } (\Leftarrow)$ :

We consider $x = \frac{a+b}{2} $. Let's show that we have $a \leq x < b $.

- 1/ We start from the inequality $a < b$. Adding $a$ on both sides and dividing by $2$, we obtain
  $$ a < x $$
  This condition straightforwardly implies that $a \leq x$
- 2/ Starting from the inequality $a < b$, we add $b$ on both sides, and divide by $2$, so that we obtain
  $$ x < b $$

The two results (1) and (2) therefore leads us to have
$$ a \leq x < b $$
As a consequence, we have $x \in [a\,,\,b)$. ($\Leftarrow$) is proved.

Comment: I don't know how to imply $a \le x <b$ from $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and $a<b$ Could you please show me the steps? And I would also be interested to know you know to define $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ so that the proof works.

Comment: @mauna I just edited my answer. Is it clearer now ? Regarding the definition of $x$, you should see it this way. Since you are given $a$ and $b$, you are *authorized* to define their mean $x$ as $x = \frac{a+b}{2}$. As we see, this number $x$ will be such that $x \in [a\,,\, b)$.